# How to customize the hotkeys in QTextEdit?

Tags: qt, telegram

I'd like to have QTextEdit use hotkeys similar to readline (e.g. alt-f/b for word movements). Is there a non-intrusive way to achieve this? To be more specific, I'd like to add readline keys to telegram-desktop https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/issues/3926

Answer (score 1):

Subclass QTextEdit and override the eventFilter and implement some specialised handling for your keys.

```
bool YOURNEWCLASS::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
// add code for checking for certain keys here
}
```

Comment: That's overly intrusive. It even needs to rebuild the entire telegram application.

Comment: Of course, you should only replace the respective QTextEdit used in that particular location. Not for all QTextEdits in the project.

Comment: By non-intrusive, I mean some way to not touch the code at all. Using a config file or preloading some DSO

Comment: Sorry, from my knowledge there is no way to do this.